# How can I convert Object of JavaScript to another type of Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a Java Script Object Like this, It has Property and Value.

```
var obj = {
   key1: 'value1',
   key2: 'value2',
   key3: 'value3',
   key4: 'value4'
}
```

how can I convert that into this format, Property into another property and value into another property and Want as array.

```
var obj = [
   {
   SettingTaget: 'key1'
   SettingValue: 'value1'
   }
   {
   SettingTaget: 'key2'
   SettingValue: 'value2'
   }
   {
   SettingTaget: 'key3'
   SettingValue: 'value3'
   }
   {
   SettingTaget: 'key4'
   SettingValue: 'value4'
   }
```

}

Comment: Iterate over Object, and push new object in the array.

Comment: Take a look at object iterators

Comment: Have a look at `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop your `obj` and create one array and push object into array.

```js
var obj = {
   key1: 'value1',
   key2: 'value2',
   key3: 'value3',
   key4: 'value4'
};
var array_obj = [];
for( var key in obj){
  array_obj.push({SettingTaget:key,SettingValue:obj[key]});
}
console.log(array_obj);
```

Comment: ah... Beat me on that

Answer (score 1):

```
    var obj = {
       key1: 'value1',
       key2: 'value2',
       key3: 'value3',
       key4: 'value4'
    }
    var newObjArray =[];  
    for(var x in obj){
     newObjArray.push({
          SettingTarget:x,
          SettingValue:obj[x]
     });
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by this way:

```
var obj = {
   key1: 'value1',
   key2: 'value2',
   key3: 'value3',
   key4: 'value4'
};
var obj1 = [];
for(var i in obj){
    obj1[obj1.length] = {"SettingTaget":i, "SettingValue":obj[i]}
}
console.info(obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the use of `Object.keys(obj)` instead of `for(key in obj)` because for more complex objects you need to check the [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) in this for-loop

```
var obj = {
   key1: 'value1',
   key2: 'value2',
   key3: 'value3',
   key4: 'value4'
};

var newObjArray = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key)
        {
          return {                
              'SettingTarget': key,
              'SettingValue': obj[key]
          };
        });

console.log(newObjArray);
```